# How do you supply a PMIC beyond its voltage limit?

Tags: power-supply, integrated-circuit

I'm using a power management IC (PMIC) with a lower max Vin than I want to supply. Is the solution to this as simple as adding a separate, greater voltage regulator in front of it?

Comment: Yes, you have to regulate the voltage down to something that the PMIC can handle.  It doesn't have to be a great regulator (can have more noise/ripple/variation than normal).  And it's not a Zener diode.

Comment: Which IC are you using?  What is your supply voltage?  How much current?

Comment: I'm using the TPS650532 (driving a TMS320DM368). The supply would be a 7.4V battery, with the DM368 not drawing more than 1A. I'm also trying to figure out if I can run a large current load (15A) off the same battery (for motors) without a huge, negative impact on the DM368.

Comment: I'm not sure the TPS650532 is best suited for your application. What is your input voltage range and what are your output voltages(s) and currents.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. It can be a switching or linear regulator.